# How do I assign to @params[] array for web service request

Tags: c#, webservices-client

I am trying to consume a Web service for which WSDL has been provided. I have added the reference service and am using the generated proxy classes / client.

The client has a method called `getUpdate` which requires a `getRequest` parameter.

The `getRequest` class has `string UserName`, `string WSName` and `@params[] @params` properties.

I've learned that the @ allows C# to use a reserved word as a property name, but I am not familiar with how to assign to the `@params` property.

See code:

```
using (var svc = new ServiceClient())
{
    getRequest request = new getRequest();
    request.UserName = "someuser"; 
    request.WSName = "somename";
    request.@params = //what do I do here?

    var result = svc.getUpdate(request);
}
```

The `@params` property is of type `@params[]` and anything I try to assign gets flagged as

> cannot implicity convert to params[]

How do I assign my parameters?

Comment: Is there also a generated class called `@params`?

Comment: Ah, I see it. See, I knew it was a stupid question. params is defined and I just didn't see it in object browser. Thank you for calling my attention to where it needed to be.

Comment: Usually IntelliSence will tell you what to create if you type `request.@params = new `.